Library not loaded AQPlayer
I'm getting the following error when building my code in XCODE
Library not loaded: @rpath/AQPlayer.framework/AQPlayer
  Referenced from: <EDD8756F-B150-3DA7-9592-394B9104E7F3> /Users/test/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/E7444FA1-2434-45B0-AD48-F7CDEE04E7A8/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/2A652B8F-49BF-4235-8B1D-A72D2A53A7F1/test.app/test

Here's my Podfile
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '13.0'
target 'test' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Minuteapp
  pod 'SwiftMessages'
  pod 'GoogleSignIn'
  pod 'Promises' 
  pod 'Flurry-iOS-SDK/FlurryMessaging'
  pod ‘Flurry-iOS-SDK/FlurrySDK’
  pod 'ApphudSDK'
  pod 'FittedSheets'
  pod 'ColorThiefSwift'
  pod "SwiftChart"
  pod 'SDWebImage'
  pod 'AQPlayer'
  pod 'STPopup'
  pod 'Toast-Swift'
  pod 'PaddingLabel'
  pod 'GoogleSignIn'
  pod 'DeviceKit'
  # pod 'SwiftyStoreKit'
  pod 'ReachabilitySwift'
  pod 'Amplitude'
  pod 'OneSignal/OneSignal', '>= 5.0.0', '< 6.0'
  pod 'OneSignal/OneSignalInAppMessages', '>= 5.0.0', '< 6.0'
  # If your app does not use CoreLocation, you can remove this:
  pod 'OneSignal/OneSignalLocation', '>= 5.0.0', '< 6.0'
end


post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH'] = 'YES'
    end
  end
    installer.generated_projects.each do |project|
          project.targets.each do |target|
              target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                  config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '13.0'
               end
          end
   end
end

As you can see, I have AQPlayer installed. So not sure why XCODE can't find AQPlayer. Can someone please help?

You need to follow these steps: 1. Quit your project. 2. run pod install 3. after pod install successful, it will create a <project_name>.xcworkspace file, you need to open it. Hopefully it will resolve your problem.
Otherwise you can drag and drop the framework as either <framework_name>.framework or <framework_name>.xcframework in your project and try to build. If still the problem persist, then please let us know. Thanks 
